# how to call a Unix subroutine from another script

Tags: linux, unix, subroutine

I have a shell script (named script_1.ksh) and I want to call a subroutine (called sun_1()) from another script (named script_2.ksh)

Is it possible that script_1.sh to be something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
script_2.sub_1()
```

Thank you,
Mikcutu.

Comment: Yes, surely it does, Thanks.

Comment: Note that most answers on this site will be for bash. Not many are using ksh.

Comment: I will test it for ksh.